# Mclaurin series from a know series with convergence of radius

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

The aim is to find the Mclaurin series approximation of the given function and to find for what value of x the function converges and radius of convergence.
$$f(x) = -x^5ln(1-2x^3)$$
from
$$f(x) = ln(x+1) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}  \frac {x^n}{n!} $$
I've got 
$$f(x) = (-1)^{n+1} \frac {(-2)^n(-x^{3n+5})} {n!} $$

I used Ratio test to check its convergence.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {(-1)^{n+2} \frac {(-2)^{n+1}(-x^{3n+8})} {(n+1)!}} {(-1)^{n+1} \frac {(-2)^n (-x^{3n+5})}{n!}}   $$

From here i simplified it too..
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac { \frac {x^8(-2)} {n+1}} {-x^5} $$
$$2x^3lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {1} {n+1} $$
and $$ |2x^3| \le 1$$
$$ -(1/2)^{1/3} \le  x \le (1/2)^{1/3} $$

Could anyone tell me if that is the right method? I will substitute the values in the series and test, but that's fine I'd like to know if this is the legal way of doing it. Sorry for skipping steps as the elaborations are very long.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If $|X|<1$ then

$$\frac {1}{1-X}=1+X+X^2+...=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}X^n $$

$$\ln (1-X)=-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {X^n}{n} $$

so if $|2x^3|<1$ then
$$\ln (1-2x^3)=-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {(2x^3)^n}{n} $$

thus

> $$f (x )=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {2^nx^{3n+5}}{n} $$

and the radius is
$$R=\frac {1}{2^\frac 13} $$

Comment: How is it $\frac {1}{n}$ ? isn't it supposed to be $ \frac{1}{n+1}? $

Comment: Ok so are you saying there was a mistake in my series expansion? because you re-arrived at radius again. I'm sorry but I'm a little too confused.

Comment: @PrathikGurudatt When using ratio test, you take absolute value. so no (-1)^n...